# Opening realm files using the realm browser

Tags: android, realm, realm-browser

I'm trying to examine my Android app's realm db contents. I've pulled my realm file from the emulator, and am now trying to open it using the Realm browser (Realm browser 2.0.1, Mac OS X El Capitan). I attempt to open the file, and the browser doesn't show anything; it's completely blank, with no Models. Tailing the file indicates that it isn't empty - what am I doing wrong here? It should be as simple as using adb to pull the file, then opening the .realm file in the editor.

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of Realm Java you're using? And would you be willing to send your Realm file to help@realm.io for us to examine?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to browse the Realm contents, use the super handy library called [Stetho-Realm](https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm)

Add the dependencies,

```
  repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
}
```

Configure it in your Application file,

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);

        Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
                        .build());
    }
}
```

Now go to Google Chrome and type in address bar,

[chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices)

Click on the connected device and start browsing the contents,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pulling your realm file to your mac all the time, now there is also option to view your realm files directly on you android device. You can use third party [Android Realm Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.min60.android.realmbrowser.free) I created, to make android development with realm little bit easier. Android app will show you all realm files on your device, and you can view all your realm files real time while testing your app.